# Cassandra 'timestamp' InvalidQueryException when Table created

Tags: java, cassandra, timestamp

I have a small table definition for Cassandra 3 as shown below.

```
create table if not exists mytable(id uuid primary key, data text, timestamp lastupdated);
```

I want to be able to map the timestamp column called 'lastupdated' to the java.time.Instant type. This can be handled according to the Cassandra documentation by registering a new Instant codec as documented here https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/custom_codecs/extras/

Following the instructions, including importing com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-extras:3.1.0 I use the following code to add the Instant codec.

```
    // Extra setup to allow Cassandra Timestamp to map to Java 8 Instant
    CodecRegistry myCodecRegistry;
    myCodecRegistry = CodecRegistry.DEFAULT_INSTANCE;
    myCodecRegistry.register(InstantCodec.instance);

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().
            addContactPoints(extractAddresses(config())).
            withCodecRegistry(myCodecRegistry).build();
```

When I debug this code I can see that my Cluster object contains the new Instant codec in the cluster.getConfiguration().codecRegistry once it has been initialized.

However, when I execute the cql that creates my table, as defined at the top, I get the following exception, via session.execute :

```
unknown type xxx.lastupdated : 
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown type xxx.lastupdated
```

I feel that I have missed something obvious as timestamp should be recognized even without the Instant codec, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is as simple as inverting the column name with the type!

```
create table if not exists mytable (
    id uuid primary key, 
    data text, 
    lastupdated timestamp
);
```

Comment: *blush* reaches for coffee pot :-) Thanks for your help !